# Stackblitz Angular 13 project does not work locally

Tags: angular, npm, stackblitz

i'm trying to download and run a simply angular 13 progect example from Stackblitz to my local pc.
Download ok, npm install ok. ng serve -o returns this message:

```
Your global Angular CLI version (13.2.5) is greater than your local version (11.0.7). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
An unhandled exception occurred: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\f.digiuseppe\Downloads\angular-ivy-dobvru\node_modules\@angular\compiler\fesm2015\compiler.mjs
See "C:\Users\F53E9~1.DIG\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-vlKUiI\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Here log:

```
[error] Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\f.digiuseppe\Downloads\angular-ivy-dobvru\node_modules\@angular\compiler\fesm2015\compiler.mjs
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:926:11)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at C:\Users\f.digiuseppe\Downloads\angular-ivy-dobvru\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\index.js:22:22
    at C:\Users\f.digiuseppe\Downloads\angular-ivy-dobvru\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\index.js:3:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\f.digiuseppe\Downloads\angular-ivy-dobvru\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\index.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\f.digiuseppe\Downloads\angular-ivy-dobvru\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:13:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
```

Node version: v14.16.1
npm version: 6.14.12

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you may check thing

1. Make sure your `package.json` includes a line for `"type": "module"`. Without this line, Node.js assumes you want to use `CommonJS` modules rather than ESM.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Tried ... maybe is not in correct position? I've inserted in before "dependencies" : { ... }

Comment: Great guess but it didn't work for me